# Using object reference after destructor (possibly) gets called

Tags: c++, asynchronous, concurrency, constructor, destructor

Suppose, I have the following code:

```
class Data
{
  private:
    int *m_arr;
    int m_size;
    bool m_deAlloc;
  public:
    Data(int *arr, int size): m_arr(arr), m_size(size), m_deAlloc(false) {}
    ~Data(){ if(m_deAlloc) delete[] m_arr; }
...
};

void foo(Data &d)
{
   // uses d ...
}  

void foo_wrapper(int *arr, int size)
{
   Data d(arr, size); // should I create it as new Data(arr, size)?

   foo(d); // asynchronous call...

} // ~Data() will be called but m_arr array will not be erased...

int main()
{
  int *arr = new int[...];
  ...
  foo_wrapper(arr,...); // internally calls foo asynchronously...
  ...
  // wait for foo execution completion....
  ...
  delete[] arr;
}
```

I tried it with gcc and it works apparently but I think it's not a valid program as "Data" reference passed to "foo" from "foo_wrapper" can be invalid as destructor of the object passed might get called before foo has finished executing (asynchronous execution). Although I don't delete data (m_arr) but still what happens with the object reference when destructor gets called?

Does the C++ (gcc) compiler just calls the destructor. For example when a destrutor for object "d" is called, does it relocate memory allocation for object "d" and set "d" to some invalid reference?

Comment: how do you allocate arr pointer?

Comment: Show real main, it depends how array initialized before passing to foo_wrapper

Comment: delete m_arr[]; is wrong, it shall be delete [] m_arr;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `Data` instance (`d`) you pass to `foo()` will just be placed on the main thread's stack -- it can certainly be destructed and out of scope (e.g. potentially reused as the main thread continues execution) before `foo()` returns. It is undefined behavior. Even if the allocation were not overwritten, you should not play with a destructed object.

One way or another, you need to ensure the parameter `d` is valid and not destructed until after `foo()` has returned.

Comment: Thanks! Does instance `d` will be placed on `foo_wrapper` function stack? If its main thread stack then when main thread stack gets destroyed? With end of `main()` func?

Comment: @user600029 you're welcome. yes, it will be allocated on `foo_wrapper`'s stack (main thread) and passed to foo (secondary thread) by *reference*. the storage for the object will not be yours to read or write to at the end of the scope (by the point `foo_wrapper` has returned).

Comment: Great, That clarifies my confusion. I got confused because it was working with gcc 4.7.1 even when the `foo` was a heavy call (finishing much later than `foo_wrapper`). I think its just a compiler+system internal thing when it "actually" de-allocates stack memory.

Comment: @user600029 would the behavior you saw maybe be explained by the fact that the compiler is free to overwrite that region of memory while or before `foo` executes?

Answer (score 1):

Depends how array was initialized. If you initialize it on stack then this is `undefined behavior` because if `foo()` is asynchronous then it's true that array can be destroyed before `foo()` finish. But if it allocated on the heap then it's safe if you delete array inside foo, or after foo call.

> But it's safer to use [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). It's perfect to manage
>   pointers between asynchronous calls.

Comment: I have edited the question now. I am using dynamic allocation for array But I dont get your point with how array on stack can get destroyed before foo finish execution?

Comment: You passing address of memory that allocated on the stack of another thread. So child thread doesnt own parent's stack and cant guarantee that memory will valid during execution